# Algorithmic Analysis and interpretation of partitions

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort, partitioning

[image: question]

So I've been working on this problem and have been stuck forever.
I don't feel like I've made any progress so any help would be great.

For i. I thought it might be the probability of being on the left of the partition multiplied by the probability of being on the right partition. So something like `(q/n)* ((n-q)/n)`. However if I were to do this, I would get the exact same thing for iii. Which doesn't seem correct.

Am I going about this correctly?

I also am unsure how to find the expected number of elements for the other parts. What does that even mean? what equation would I make to solve this?

How are we supposed to know the expected if it could really be anything?
I know that the qth position is sorted so how would I use that to solve it?

Comment: Did you miss out some text that assumes that each element is different, and that all permutations of the array are initially equally likely?

Answer (score 0):

First, assume each permutation is equally likely, and that all the elements in the array are different.

Any particular element that's originally to the left of q, is equally likely to go in any of the remaining places in the array. That means it's got probability 1 - q/n of moving to the right. Similarly, an element originally to the right of q has probability (q - 1)/n of moving to the left. Because of the way the partition has been implemented, an element never moves from left to a different place on the left, or right to a different place on the right.

Expectation is linear, and the expected number of moves of a single element is simply its probability of moving. Therefore the expected number of moves from right to left is the product of the probability of moving times the number of elements originally on the right, or (n - q)(q - 1)/n. Similarly, the expected number of moves from left to right is (q - 1)(1 - q/n). So given a particular q, the expectation is the sum of these two, which is 2(n - q)(q - 1)/n.

Now, to get the overall expected number of moves excluding the movement of the partition element, we have to sum up over q, each q being equally likely:

1/n * sum(q=0 to n-1) 2(n - q)(q - 1) / n.

Simplifying, this equals (n^2 - 3n - 4) / 3n.

Finally, we have to add the expected number of moves of the partition which is (n - 1)/n (since it moves except when it happens to be the smallest element in the array).

Simplifying again, this gives (n^2 - 2n - 5) / n.

(Assuming I didn't make an error in calculation along the way!)

Answer (score 0):

Like @Anonymous, I'll assume the elements are all different and the permutations are equally likely.

Let's address the first question first and let's solve the inverse problem. That is:

i. What is the probability that no element moved from the left to the right of `q`.

Before finding this out, I'd like to point out that if no element moved from the left to the right, therefore no element moved from the right to the left either. This implies that the answer to questions `i.` and `iii.` are the same, and so are the answers to questions `ii.` and `iv.`. In fact, this is easy to establish by symmetry.

So, let's calculate that probability. Let's divide the possible cases by the value of `q` and sum up. For any given `q` (`q` starts from 1), you have `q-1` numbers that are smaller than it. You also have `q-1` slots on the left and `n-q` slots on the right. To total possible permutations of the `n-1` numbers (excluding the pivot which is at position `q`) is `(n-1)!`. The number of cases where the smaller `q-1` numbers are on the left, and the larger `n-q` numbers are on the right is `(q-1)!(n-q)!`. The probability of this happening is therefore:

```
(q-1)!(n-q)!
------------
   (n-1)!
```

To get the total chances, we sum all possible cases divided by `n` (Note: what we calculated was a conditional probability. The set of possibilities can be divided by the value of `q` into distinct subsets whose union covers the whole set. In other words, the complete probability can be calculated as the sum of probabilities in each subset multiplied by the probability of that subset. The probability of the pivot ending in location `q` is `1/n`).

```
         n
     1  ___  (q-1)!(n-q)!
p = --- \    ------------
     n  /__     (n-1)!
        q=1
```

This was the chance that no element moves from the left to the right. The chance of having at least one element move is thus `1-p`. This could also be rewritten as:

```
           n
       1  ___     (q-1)!(n-q)!
p_1 = --- \  (1 - ------------)
       n  /__        (n-1)!
          q=1
```

where `p_1` is the probability for question `i.`. Note that the term inside the sigma is indeed the chance for a given `q` that at least some element moved from left to right. Let's call this `p_1q` as the probability for question `i.` given a fixed `q`.

---

To answer the second question, we know that the expected value would be the sum of the expected value given a `q` multiplied by the chances for that `q`. Chances for `q` being any value is `1/n`, as stated before. Now, what is the expected value of number of elements on the left that need to move to right given some `q`? This is itself the sum of different values multiplied by their probability.

Let's say given a `q`, there are `k` values on the left that need to move to the right. In other words, there are `k` values larger than the pivot at position `q` and `q-k-1` values smaller than the pivot. What are these chances? You need to calculate this again with combinatorics, where `k` of the `q-1` elements on the left are selected from the `q-1` values smaller than the pivot. Unfortunately, this answer is taking up longer than I expected and I really need to get back to work (plus, typing equations without latex math is painful). Hope this would help you continue solving this problem yourself.